# How to use 2nd Tkinter window to change image in 1st?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quick summary: The green button is supposed to change when an image is selected, but it doesn't:

[image]

I have a Tkinter `window-A` with a button that when pressed will use a separate Python file to create a new `window-B`. `Window-B` has two buttons: new screen-snip or select image from folder. The method used for this is supposed to then change `self.image_selected` so that it can be used to update the button in `window-A` to have this new image.

I've tried both lines of code below, and neither are working. I'm not getting any errors either:

```
        self.button.configure(image = img.image_selected) # first try
        self.button['image'] = img.image_selected         # second try
```

Here is my code (simplified for clarity):

```
import tkinter as tk
import get_image_or_snip

class ButtonImg:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.newWindow = None
        self.master = master
        self.title = "My Minimum Reproducible Example"
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(height = 5)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(bg="#93d9cc", height = 5, text = "Select Image",
                                font = self.fontA, command = self.changeImage)
        self.button.pack(fill="both")

    def changeImage(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        img = get_image_or_snip.AcquireImage(self.newWindow)
        self.button.configure(image = img.image_selected)
        #self.button['image'] = img.image_selected

root = tk.Tk()
app = ButtonImg(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the aforementioned `get_image_or_snip.py` code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import snipping_tool


class AcquireImage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="#1B2631")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Image File", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command =lambda: self.show_dialogs(1))
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Get Screen Snip", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command=lambda: self.show_dialogs(2))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.image_selected = None
        self.master.mainloop()

    def show_dialogs(self, method):
        if method == 1:
            ret = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            load_img = Image.open(ret)
            self.image_selected = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load_img)

        if method == 2:
            ret = snipping_tool.get_snip()
            self.image_selected = ret


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    AcquireImage(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I can also post the `snipping_tool.py` code if that would be helpful. However, it seems that neither option is working now, so I don't think that's where the problem is.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe send first window as argument to second window and then second window you will have access to all variables in first window. All widgets get parent as first variable to have access to parent - and you can do the same with your windows.

Comment: I see one problem - your second window use second `mainloop()` and it never ends (never `destroy()` second window) - so it never goes to line `self.button.configure(image = img.image_selected)`. If you add some `print()` in code then you will see which part of code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `print()` before and after `get_image_or_snip.AcquireImage(self.newWindow)` in `changeImage()` then you should see only first text because you run second `mainloop()` and it never ends this loop and never go back to `changeImage()` and never runs `self.button.configure(image=img.image_selected)`

You should use only one `mainloop()` and eventually use

```
root.wait_window(self.newWindow)
```

to wait until you close second window  and then it will run `self.button.configure(image=img.image_selected)`

But there are other problems.

It removes image from memory memory when second windows is destroyed so you have to assign it to variable in first window.

Button use height in chars when you sent text but when you assign image then it use height in pixels and you have to change it from `5` to image.height()`

---

All code in one file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk


class AcquireImage:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="#1B2631")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Image File", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font=self.fontA, command=lambda:self.show_dialogs(1))
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Get Screen Snip", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font=self.fontA, command=lambda:self.show_dialogs(2))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.image_selected = None

    def show_dialogs(self, method):
        
        if method == 1:
            ret = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/home/user/images/')
            if ret:
                self.image_selected = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=ret)
                self.master.destroy()
     
        elif method == 2:
            self.image_selected = snipping_tool.get_snip()


class ButtonImg:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.newWindow = None
        self.master = master
        self.title = "My Minimum Reproducible Example"
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(height=5)
        self.canvas.pack()
        
        self.button = tk.Button(bg="#93d9cc", height=5, text="Select Image",
                                font=self.fontA, command=self.changeImage)
        self.button.pack(fill="both")

    def changeImage(self):
        print('open second window')
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        img = AcquireImage(self.newWindow)
        self.master.wait_window(self.newWindow)
        print('close second window')

        if img.image_selected: # check if image was selected
            self.image = img.image_selected
            self.button.configure(image=self.image, height=self.image.height())
        

root = tk.Tk()
app = ButtonImg(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** If you want to change image without closing second window then you should send first window (or button from first window)  as argument to second window and change image in `show_dialogs()`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk


class AcquireImage:
    
    def __init__(self, master, first_window):
        self.master = master
        self.first_window = first_window
        
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="#1B2631")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Image File", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font=self.fontA, command=lambda:self.show_dialogs(1))
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Get Screen Snip", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font=self.fontA, command=lambda:self.show_dialogs(2))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.image_selected = None

    def show_dialogs(self, method):
        
        if method == 1:
            ret = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/home/user/images/')
            if ret:
                self.image_selected = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=ret)
                self.first_window.image = self.image_selected
                self.first_window.button.configure(image=self.first_window.image, height=self.first_window.image.height())

        elif method == 2:
            self.image_selected = snipping_tool.get_snip()


class ButtonImg:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.newWindow = None
        self.master = master
        self.title = "My Minimum Reproducible Example"
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(height=5)
        self.canvas.pack()
        
        self.button = tk.Button(bg="#93d9cc", height=5, text="Select Image",
                                font=self.fontA, command=self.changeImage)
        self.button.pack(fill="both")

    def changeImage(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        img = AcquireImage(self.newWindow, self) # first window as `self` but you can send `self.button`

        

root = tk.Tk()
app = ButtonImg(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Doc about creating [Dialog Windows](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)